# Decimal Values scaling and precision in Datastage 11.5

Tags: datastage, transformer-model, ibm-infosphere

I have a column of decimal (5,5). I want to put default value as "+000.00000". I tried with several options such in meta data such as setting precision=5 or using the option "Packed to no(separate)", setting sign position=leading, but all I am getting value as "+000000". How can I correct this?

Comment: How do you check these values? Why should +000.00000 be a decimal(5,5)?

Comment: So I have to do a subtraction between two decimal values and based on outcome convert assign +000.00000 if output is negative (apparently this is default value). Although I am getting 000.00000 but the decimal goes away when I add sign.

Comment: What does " the decimal goes away when I add sign" mean? Are you writing to a SequentialFile stage? Are you looking at the data via View data?

Comment: Yes I am writing in a sequential file. And no I am not looking via view data. For  the decimal goes away when I add sign" ->  when I edit the metadata of column and use parameter "packed= no(separate) and sign position=leading"  I get output as +00000000 (where period goes away). And this is when I checked in the file